# How to use string names in loop like form controls?

Tags: excel, vba

In form controls we can use `{ controls("Textbox"&1) }` as for loops.

My question is I have already defined the String as D1,D2,D3. I want to use like D as common and suffix as variable

```
sub abcd ()
    dim i, k as integer
    dim D1 as string
    dim D2 as string

    k="abcd1"

    for i = 1 to 2
        if k<> "" then              'like controls("textbox" & i ) for loop
            "D"&i = true
        Else "D" & i+1

end sub
```

It shows a messagebox with the error:

> expected : line number or label or statement or end of statement

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You've defined `k` as an `integer` and trying to hold a string value in it.

Answer (score 1):

This code has several (actually a lot) of issues:

1. `Dim i, k As Integer` declares `k As Integer` but `i As Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable.
2. You declare `D1` as `String` but `True` is a `Boolean`.
3. If you declare `Dim D1 As String` you cannot access the variabele with `"D" & i = True`. This is no valid syntax. Therefore you would need to use an array:

   ```
   Dim MyArray(1 To 2) As Boolean
   ```

   So you can access it like

   ```
   MyArray(i) = True   'where i can be 1 or 2
   ```
4. If you declare `k As Integer` that means `k` repersents a number (without decimals). So you cannot put text in there `k = "abcd1"`, this will produce a type missmatch. Also comparing `k` against a string (text) `""` like `If k <> "" Then` will missmatch since `k` is a number.

   Also have a look at [data type summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) to study which data type to use for which kind of data.
5. Your `For i = 1 To 2` loop is missing a `Next i` in the end of the loop.
6. Your `If` statement is missing a `End If` in the end.

So in general I can only recommend you to study some tutorials or books about the basic syntax of VBA, you are lacking a lot of basic things.

So the following example might help you:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyArray(1 To 3) As Boolean

    For i = 1 To 3
        MyArray(i) = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will correct it and try it again